# monerod.exe Inbound malicious attacks

Tags: monero-wallet-gui, monerod

I just installed Monero GUI Wallet for the first time and during the sync, I am getting a LOT of inbound malicious attacks.  Malwarebytes is blocking them but why am I getting them?  How is it that people from all over the world suddenly know my IP address so they can try to attack my computer?  And how can I stop the attack?

Answer (score 2):

> I am getting a LOT of inbound malicious attacks

What makes you think they are "malicious attacks"?

When you run the Monero daemon it connects to the network and syncs with other nodes (which means inbound and outbound traffic from other peoples computers).

> Malwarebytes is blocking them but why am I getting them?

An excerpt from the main [downloads](https://www.getmonero.org/downloads/) page:

> #### Antivirus
>
> Be aware that some antiviruses and firewalls may flag the Monero executables and archives as malware. More info in the [FAQ](https://www.getmonero.org/get-started/faq/#antivirus).

And from it's linked [FAQ](https://www.getmonero.org/get-started/faq/#antivirus):

> ##### Why is my antivirus/firewall flagging the Monero software i just downloaded as malware?
>
> After you have downloaded the Monero software (GUI and CLI alike), your antivirus or firewall may flag the executables as malware. Some antiviruses only warn you about the possible menace, others go as far as silently removing your downloaded wallet / daemon. This likely happens because of the integrated miner, which is used for mining and for block verification. Some antiviruses may erroneously consider the miner as dangerous software and act to remove it.